# How do I filter by date time datatypes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, jupyter-notebook

I have a data frame where I need to filter by rows where `registration date` is equal to `enrolment date` below was the code I wrote that gave an error

```
master_data = master_data.query("registration date" == "enrolment date")
```

Note: the two columns are datetime datatype

Comment: What is the error? And why don't you simply use something like: `master_data[master_data["registration date"] == myDate]`

Comment: ValueError: expr must be a string to be evaluated, <class 'bool'> given

Comment: Try this `master_data = master_data.query("registration date == enrolment date")`

Comment: Your problem is that you're comparing if two strings are equal to eachother. You need to delete the two inner quotes, leaving only the two outer ones.

Comment: @AmirhosseinKiani I can't see any reference to "enrolment date" in your code as I need to be the two dates to be equal

Comment: If your dataframe has two columns named "enrolment date" and "registration date", my answer will work fine, otherwise, you need first to define the date.

Comment: @richardec the code worked but nothing showed in my df when I ran the code, i.e all the columns and rows were blank

Comment: You might need to do `master_data = master_data[master_data.query("'registration date' == enrolment date'")]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can use something like:

```
master_data = master_data[master_data["registration date"] == master_data["enrolment date"]]
```

Comment: I got this error. SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: @BabatundeRahman If you just copied and pasted my code, you probably got an error because I didn't close the bracket properly. I have edited the answer as per your comment.

Comment: Please don't answer duplicate questions :)